# Missing ; before statement (Jira Addon - oAuth)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, oauth, jira

I get the error:

> [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding windows-1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
>
> [INFO] Compiling javascript using YUI
>
> [ERROR] missing ; before statement let privateKeyData = fs.readFileSync('location','utf-8');

As shown I have put the `;` before `let`. I don't understand the error. I am creating an add-on for Jira. I started the JS file via cmd and it worked. However when I want to package the project I get that error. Please help.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var initmyConfluenceMacro = function() {
    $(".myConfluenceMacro").each(function() {
      const request = require('request');
      const fs = require('fs');
      let privateKeyData = fs.readFileSync('filelocation', 'utf-8');
      const oauth = {
        consumer_key: 'mykey',
        consumer_secret: privatkey,
        token: 'mytoken',
        token_secret: 'tokensecret',
        signature_method: 'signaturemethod'
      };

      request.get({
        url: 'thelink',
        oauth: oauth,
        qs: null,
        json: true
      }, function(e, r, user) {
        console.log(user)
      });

      var html = "output";
      $(this).html(html);
    });
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    initmyConfluenceMacro();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Maybe it's somewhere else or you just paste code wrong?

Comment: Pf I don't get it. Can it be that it can't package the node_modules with it? I run the same code in cmd and it works :S It shouldn't be somewhere else because I only call it in my main and that's it.

Comment: You're compiling with YUI, it looks like, and YUI has not been maintained in a really long time (over 4 years). The parser it uses has many problems.

Comment: @Justinas When I run it with cmd it works fine. Can the problem be that I want to read a file from my pc, but I want to put the js file in a jar. This is another question, but can you maybe point me, on how to read the file / the private key from my jar to js? I put the private key with my js together in the resources folder. (And this is a maven project) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for the error is

> const fs = require('fs');

fs is for (as on their page) security reasons removed from Atlassian and cannot be used. My workaround was to use the velocity template, in order to import the file, and then to parse it to the js file.

I hope this helps. If someone has other ideas please let me know.